# Icq with Pidgin: timeout error

Tags: pidgin, timeout

When I try to connect with Icq through Pidgin I get this error message: "Received unexpected response from https://api.icq.net/aim/startOSCARSession: Request Timeout".
It was a problem in 2010: then fixed diabling client login or ssl; now that solution does not work.
Any idea?